# Reinstalling MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

We currently try to reinstall MySQL 5.7 on a Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Box

But the installation fails with this error:

```
#sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client --fix-broken --fix-missing

[...]
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems — leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.27) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

We have purged the previous installation.
`sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*`

Seems to work just fine, no error Messages. Afterwards we check with:

```
#dpkg-query -l mysql-server
dpkg-query: no packages found matching mysql-server
```

In addition, we have manually removed remaining folders, to make sure there are no leftovers which could interfere with a new install.

`rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql`

But still, every new try of installing still fails with that error.
Does someone know what we can do to fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would try first remove MySQL:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt autoremove
sudo mv -iv /var/lib/mysql /var/tmp/mysql-backup
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*
```

After this, I would install MySQL again:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Try this, and let me know, if it worked or not

Comment: Thank you, but that gt us an error also. After the 
`sudo apt install mysql-server`  
`Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.
`